# pgfplots: print rounded values with statistical errors in parentheses

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I recently discovered pgfplotstable and it is great to typeset auto-generated tables. Consider, for example, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[sci zerofill]{
  mean       error
  123.123929 45
  1.091234   0.87
  1.1        2.2
}
\end{document}
```

It correctly outputs two columns "mean" and "error", with appropriate rounding.

However, I would like to output the data in the following form

```
123(45)
1.09(87)
1.1(2.2)
```

where the values in parentheses are the statistical errors.
Is there a way to achieve this using pgfplots?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
  mean       error
  123.123929 45
  1.091234   0.87
  1.1        2.2
}\datatable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\RowNum{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\noindent\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\RowNum}{%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{mean}\of{\datatable}%
\pgfmathprintnumber[sci zerofill]{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{error}\of{\datatable}%
(\pgfmathprintnumber[sci zerofill]{\pgfplotsretval})\\%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sure, but your suggestion does not follow the usual convention (sorry, I should have made the notation clearer): 123.12(45) would mean 123.12 \pm 0.45 and not 123 \pm 45 as in the data. 1.09(0.87) is not wrong but unusual: I would expect 1.09(87).

Comment: I had lua code that I used to use in conjunction with lualatex that does what I want but I hoped to find a solution in pgfplots...

Comment: @jafasi To be honest, if you find this confusing, then so is your data. In the first case the 45 is probably a real 45, but in the second row you want 87 to represent 0.87. This is all fine but IMHO orthogonal to the scope of this site. My answer only tells you how to bring the answer in the form you asked for, not to do some magic to it. How would the compiler know when you want to typeset what unless you tell it to it by either giving it the data in the form or by specifying clear rules how to manipulate it?

Comment: Well, this is common scientific practice and pretty common in many fields of physics. I am grateful for your answer but it is not the form I asked for. The convention is to give only digits that differ from the mean value and it is in no way arbitrary. I do have code to do this and I just wondered if there is a way within pgfplots itself, since it is pretty common and pgfplots already has some ways to manipulate output formats. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: If your data is correct, you should reconsider your measurements or calculations. You give a measurement result with 9 significant digits but an error value of only 2. This is by no means a scientific standard but a pointless statement! If the error value has only two significant digits, you can only give two for the measured value too! Your correct result would, therefore, be 120 +- 45. Here, however, you would have to ask yourself why you only have 2 significant digits for the error if you were able to measure 9.